# Careers: searching by keyword often returns unrelated results

Tags: feature-request, bug, jobs, search

When searching for the term "product manager" very few of the results are for that job.

When searching for some technology like "google tag manager" almost none of the results are for that technology.

Does anyone have advice to help search?

Also, is there any way to limit a search to just job title, or company, vs only keywords?

Answer (score 7):

We are working on more advanced search capabilities, including searching by title, tags, seniority and compensation requirements but they're a bit delayed behind other work at the moment. Expect something in the next 6-8 weeks :)!

It would seem that searching for this particular technology isn't really yielding any useful results on the job board. It's probably the case that this particular technology isn't something commonly mentioned by employers... A cursory analysis of the SO questions using the [google-tag-manager](/questions/tagged/google-tag-manager) tag indicates that 54% of them use the [google-analytics](/questions/tagged/google-analytics) tag as well.

I'd suggest thinking about other technologies that are related to what you want to work with and go from there.

Comment: Thanks :) I was using that as an example, but notice similar results for `product manager`, which yields results containing `product` and/or `manager`. Looking forward to the enhancements!

Comment: @dean I hope that creating triggers based on seniority will be included there, that would be very useful.

Comment: Hi Dean, Curious if there has been any progress on improving search functionality for careers? It would really come in handy ;)

Comment: @d-_-b we're working on exposing more advanced capabilities for job search in the UI, in the meantime you can use [advanced search syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/help/search-jobs) to better filter results